# Linq - where not in comma separated list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object named game which has a property called channels (which is comma separated since a game can relate to more then one channel).

I also have a channel object, which contains a property called isActive.

What I need, is a way to get all the games that have active channels.

I started writing this:

```
var oGames = games.AllActive.Where(
    g => !g.StateProperties.Channels.Contains(
        channels.All.Where(c => c.StateProperties.IsActive).ToArray()
    );
```

but got blocked... anyone can help me ?

Comment: well, first of all .Contains accepts strings only ( not channel objects ), if i will convert the result Array, then .Contains will still compare the exact string that appears in g.stateproperties.channels to the exact result comming from .channels.all....

Comment: Why are you keeping a "comma separated list" aka string, when you could be using a *real* `List`? Is there a reason to write stringly-typed code in C#?

Comment: even if you are right, i cannot go and change the whole working model after 5 years of development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var oGames = games.AllActive
    .Where(g => g.StateProperties.Channels.Split(',')
                 .Intersect(channels.Where(c => c.StateProperties.IsActive)
                                    .Select(c => c.Name)).Any());
```

I'd strongly recommend moving away from a csv of channel names, and instead store a reference to them.

This would simplify the code quite a lot. Using a dictionary mapping strings to channels would also help.

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Intersect<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You might need to change `.Select(c => c.Name)` based on what property defines your channels names.

Comment: i did change it ( .Guid ) since that is what appears in .channels

Comment: My guess is that `Guid` isn't a `string` then. So you could do `Guid.ToString()`. But i'd stress, you should move away from storing the channel names as strings in your game object.

Comment: @Dementic: even if this solution will work for your situation, I think your game.channels property should be a IList<channel>, instead of a string. This way, more object oriented, you could perform Linq queries more easly.

Comment: `Where` needs a predicate. I added a call to `Any`.

Comment: @Martinho, well spotted. Gets a bit confusing with no IDE and lots of nested expressions!

Comment: the code works now,
but i have a little question, since Games Object and Channels Object are two diffrent objects, and the Games.State.Channels, is used only to know what games belong to what channel, is that so important that it is comma seperated ?